# Create unique link (one time click) with expiration time

Tags: php

I want to create unique links (one time click) for my newsletters.

Look the steps:

1. I will create a link, or can be a script that will create the link http://www.example.com/page.php?unique=email@email.com
2. My subscriber will receive a newsletter which contains this link.
3. They click/visit this newsletter/link.
4. If they want visit it again they can't, the link will be expired, and the subscriber will be redirected to other page http://www.example.com/expired.php

So is there any chance to create this? How can this be accomplished?

I have this code

```
<?php

    include("variables.php");

    $password = trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    if($password == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
        // Create a new key
        $new = uniqid('key',TRUE);

        if(!is_dir('keys')) {
            mkdir('keys');
            $file = fopen('keys/.htaccess','w');
            fwrite($file,"Order allow,deny\nDeny from all");
            fclose($file);
        }

        $file = fopen('keys/keys','a');
        fwrite($file,"{$new}\n");
        fclose($file);
?>
```

This script is located in a file named generate.php and if I access this url ( http://www.example.com/generate.php?1234 - 1234 is the password to generate a unique ID) will generate a unique link like this http://www.example.com/page.php?key525e1200e3a5f9.19949496 that will be only 1 time available!

Now what I want is, to access http://www.example.com/generate.php?1234&s=email@email.com

And this this generate a unique link http://www.example.com/page.php?key525e1200e3a5f9.19949496&s=email@email.com

This is for a protected download page! I need to add the user email to the download page, and this to be generated by link. 's' is the variable that will be get by the download page using $_GET['s']

Understand what I mean?

Comment: I found how to [protect a download link using a unique URL](http://blog.focusoft.ro/2012/07/14/protecting-a-download-link-using-a-unique-url.htm). But I can't figure out how to use this script for my uses.

Comment: So what? Were's the question?

Comment: That tutorial seems pretty good. What is the problem? Are you expecting someone to write the code for you? Have a try, then come back when you get stuck.

Comment: Add a column in your database in your users table called unique_link. Have it default to 0. Have the page make sure the column is 0 to view the page, and when the user visits the page, set the column to 1.

Comment: @ScottHelme The tutorial is not really good. The principles may apply, but using the old MySQL extension is not acceptable (the article is from 2012).

Comment: Converting to PDO is not really that difficult...

Comment: @Scott Helme I don't expect someone to write the code for me, I expecting someone to show me something similar to what I need!

Comment: I found the solution:

`<?php

 include("variables.php");
 
 $password = trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

 if($password == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
  // Create a new key
  $new = uniqid('key',TRUE);
  
  if(!is_dir('keys')) {
   mkdir('keys');
   $file = fopen('keys/.htaccess','w');
   fwrite($file,"Order allow,deny\nDeny from all");
   fclose($file);
  }
  
  $file = fopen('keys/keys','a');
  fwrite($file,"{$new}\n");
  fclose($file);
?>`

this script generate a link like this site.com/page.php?key525e0acd163592.31766032

Comment: Now I want to add a custom string in this link, I mean, for example I want to send in the newsletter this link:

site.com/page.php?key525e0acd163592.31766032?s=email@email.com

and the string/value s=email@email.com to print in my page the email@email.com.

Comment: @Scott Helme Like you said, I gave a try, now I need help!

Comment: Check my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395203/add-a-variable-that-will-be-echo-on-page-next-to-uniqid maybe is more explicit!

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using there email.

Then do a PHP page with the following statements.
Request the GET (in this case the email address) and check if it exists in database table (lets call this - hasvisited).

IF this exists then redirect to page you want.

If doesnt exist then...
1.) Add it to DB.
2.) display 1 time page.

When step 1 happens. it will stop the user from visiting again.

If you want to restrict this to a group of specific users - as the above solution people could theoritcally type anything to get past this...

I would create table with the users already and do an IF state on a column called 'visits' and if 1 or less allow and add +1 to visits column. if above 1 visit then redirect.

I hope this make sense - should also be fairly simple to implement using PHP, MySQL DB and simple IF statement.

Comment: Easy to day, hard to do it, since I don't know PHP so well.