# Add a variable that will be echo on page next to uniqid

Tags: php

I have this code

```
<?php

    include("variables.php");

    $password = trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    if($password == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
        // Create a new key
        $new = uniqid('key',TRUE);

        if(!is_dir('keys')) {
            mkdir('keys');
            $file = fopen('keys/.htaccess','w');
            fwrite($file,"Order allow,deny\nDeny from all");
            fclose($file);
        }

        $file = fopen('keys/keys','a');
        fwrite($file,"{$new}\n");
        fclose($file);
?>
```

This script is located in a file named generate.php and if I access this url ( `http://www.site.com/generate.php?1234` - 1234 is the password to can generate a unique ID) will generate a unique link like this `http://www.site.com/page.php?key525e1200e3a5f9.19949496` that will be only 1 time available!

Now what I want is to access `http://www.site.com/generate.php?1234?s=email@email.com`

And this this generate a unique link `http://www.site.com/page.php?key525e1200e3a5f9.19949496?s=email@email.com`

This is for a protected download page! I need to can add the user email to the download page, and this to be generated by link! s is the variable that will be get by the download page with `$_GET['s']`

Understand what I mean?

Comment: You need an `&` sign between each variable of the URL. E.g.: http://localhost/mypage.php?firstvar=firstvalue&secondvar=secondvalue

Comment: @FMC Okay, but explain me where to put `&$_GET['s']` ? That you mean right ?

Comment: No, I mean the way you construct your URL. You need to construct it properly so that $_GET gets populated with the data it contains.

Comment: I edited my question, I hope I edited in the right way, I'm not a coder! What I want to do is to create unique URL by accessing generate.php?1234 (remember 1234 is the password). Now that work the unique URL is created, but I want to create a unique URL with a custom email added in, and that email to be can $_GET on the download page. Thanks for help. Hope you will show me the way to do this, and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @FMC I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. But I would recommend placing the "secret code" in a variable as well. Perhaps `$_GET['email']` is not available because the URL is a bit "funky". Rework your URL to use `mypage.php?secret=abc&email=blah`, and forget about using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, use `$_GET['secret']` instead. I hope I made sense.

Comment: Look the variables.php code, maybe then I will more clear:
`<?

 define('PROTECTED_DOWNLOAD','1.php');
  
  define('DOWNLOAD_PATH','/page.php');
 
 define('SUGGESTED_FILENAME','1.php');
 
 define('ADMIN_PASSWORD','1234');
 
 define('EXPIRATION_DATE', '+36 hours');
 
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
 header("Expires: ".date('U', strtotime(EXPIRATION_DATE)));
 
?>`

Comment: Like I said I'm not a coder, I just need a code to add there in my script to can echo a word on the download page.