# How can I make a page expire after user visit it?

Tags: php

I have a page http://www.mysite.com/newsletter.php

Now I want to put a variable there when I send you an email and you visit this page to see you email/username there.

So I email you this link http://www.mysite.com/newsletter.php?user=email@email.com

Now when you will access this link you will see you email/username on that page as "Hello email@email.com, check out new blog"

I write the username/email on that page with

```
<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>
```

Now how can I make this page to expire after you visit it? I mean I want to visit it only once time!

***EDITED**

Look the code I use already to generate unique links that expire:

```
<?php

    include("variables.php");

    $password = trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    if($password == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
        $new = uniqid('key',TRUE);

        if(!is_dir('keys')) {
            mkdir('keys');
            $file = fopen('keys/.htaccess','w');
            fwrite($file,"Order allow,deny\nDeny from all");
            fclose($file);
        }

        $file = fopen('keys/keys','a');
        fwrite($file,"{$new}\n");
        fclose($file);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page created</title>
        <style>
            nl { 
                font-family: monospace 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page key created</h1>
        Your new single-use page link:<br>
        <nl>
        <?php 
            echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . DOWNLOAD_PATH . "?" . $new; 
        ?></nl>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    } else {

        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
?>`
```

Also this code expire in 36 hours, and is set by variables.php

```
<?

    define('PROTECTED_DOWNLOAD','download.php');

    define('DOWNLOAD_PATH','/.work/page.php');

    define('SUGGESTED_FILENAME','download-doc.php');

    define('ADMIN_PASSWORD','1234');

    define('EXPIRATION_DATE', '+36 hours');

    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: ".date('U', strtotime(EXPIRATION_DATE)));

?>
```

This php files generates a link like this:  http://www.mysite.com/page.php?key1234567890
Now how to add the variable user=email@email.com next to uniqid to generate a link like this: **page.php?key1234567890&user=email@email.com** to can get the email@email.com by `<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>` in the next page.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store a status variable in the database, when you have a visit on that page then compare the email with the one stored in the database having 0 visits so far, update the status variable to show visited=1 and next time when same url is opened, look at the status variable and since its 1, don't show that page.

Comment: Can you help me with an example? I'm not a good coder, I still learn! And this can be do it without a database? Maybe cookies or uniqid ?

Comment: Not really, I think that's very simple. Please share some code that you have so far and I ll gladly help you finish it up

Comment: Look, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411656/single-use-download-script-modification and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395203/add-a-variable-that-will-be-echo-on-page-next-to-uniqid

Comment: I still try to get an option, check there maybe you can help me, I will send you a beer :D

Comment: So in conclusion I have already a script to create a link that will expire after visit but how to add this variable user=email@email.com to can post it in the next page?

Comment: That's sweet of you but people at stack overflow tend to help others without looking for any incentive :) Bring the relevant code out of those questions here on this question and lets see where we end up

Comment: You can see the relevant code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411656/single-use-download-script-modification

Comment: I just edited my question, look now maybe you will see what I need to do and can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid interacting with a database, you could also create a cookie, and then look at the cookie when someone navigates to http://www.mysite.com/newsletter.php. The only problem with this is that the page will appear again when the user clears his/her cookies.

Comment: Check my other comments please, maybe you will can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your tags are accurate, I can point you in a general direction on cookie interaction with JS. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Cookies are not a good way to make the page single-use. If I clear my cookies, I can see the page again.

Comment: Hence why I pointed that out. I posted it simply as an alternative to a database solution. It's much more light weight, but with that said, it has its own quirks. I still think it's a very reasonable solution, though.

Comment: @Franklin Maybe you have right, Javascript can't do what I need so I deleted that tag. Look on this post, maybe you will get the point, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411656/single-use-download-script-modification

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can only do this with database update mechanism safely.
Set database field with 0 default and make it 1 after user visit that page.

For Example,

In some website you find such options in Forget Password Link Page

Comment: Can you give me a sample of code or a link where I can see something like that?

Answer (score 0):

another option will be using client side cache for this. We can save a cookie the first time the user visits and on next visit we can check if user is visited earlier and display him message.   http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 0):

Just add an extra column into your K. Which will store the status of the page. When user visite your page. Just change the status. And don't allow pages whose status is changed. You can easily do it with minor change in database query. That will remove lot of burden of maintaining using `session` and `cookies`.